# FluentNHibernate doubles ColumnName when using IComponentConvention maps (v1.3.0.727)?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

This works in v.717 (IComponentConvention) :

```
    public void Apply(IComponentInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Type == typeof(EmailAddress))
        {
            instance.Properties.First(property => property.Name == "FullAddress")).Column(instance.Name);
        }
    }
```

Using the above convention I can map the name of my database column to the name of the component property. But in v.727 the hbm suddenly looks like this:

```
<component name="DefaultMailAddressForAlerts" class="EmailAddress"> 
    <property name="FullAddress" type="System.String"> 
        <column name="DefaultMailAddressForAlertsDefaultMailAddressForAlerts"/>          
    </property> 
</component>
```

Making the column name in the database the name of the component property x 2. Is there a new way of creating component conventions in v727 of fluent nhibernate?

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/161

Comment: @JamesGregory You can just post that as an answer, and we can mark the question as answered, since it's a bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug. I've raised an issue in our bugtracker, see [Fluent NHibernate #161](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/161).